# Do custom errors and events take up storage in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, events, storage, custom-errors

For example, is slot 0 in this contract the `uint256 x` or does the custom `error` take up this slot? Same thing for events.

```
contract Foo {

error CustomError();
uint256 x;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, events and errors aren't stored in contract storage like state variables are.

For example take these three contracts:

```
contract A {
    uint x;
}
```

```
contract B {
    error Zero();
    error One();
    error Two();
    error Three();
    error Four();
    error Five();
    error Six();
    error Seven();
    uint x;
}
```

```
contract C {
    event Zero();
    event One();
    event Two();
    event Three();
    event Four();
    event Five();
    event Six();
    event Seven();
    uint x;
}
```

Each contract cost the same amount of gas to deploy:

```
 gas    77126 gas
transaction cost    67072 gas 
execution cost  12666 gas
```

And each contract showed the same size, `0.063 kB`, when using `forge build --sizes`.